# How to use column value in AS of SELECT FOR XML statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, select

I have reduced this sample to the absolute necessary minimum. So I'm aware, that it does not make sense :-)

I know, I can select XML from a table with the following query:

```
select id as [Direction/@Id],
        direction  as [Direction]
from devicepdo
for xml path('')
```

The result will look like this:

```
<Direction Id="1">I</Direction>
<Direction Id="2">O</Direction>``
<Direction Id="3">I</Direction>
<Direction Id="4">O</Direction>
....
```

The column direction always contains I or O, and I want to change the enclosing XML Tag depending on the column value.

My result should look like this:

```
<In Id="1">I</In>
<Out Id="2">O</Out>``
<In Id="3">I</In>
<Out Id="4">O</Out>
....
```

All my tries to use a variable or colum in the "AS" clause failed.

In my query, the "**Direction**" in "as [**Direction**/@Id]" should be variable depending on the column value.

Is this possible? Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all attributes are null, and the contents is null, no tag will be generated. You can use this fact to generate different types of tags depending on values in each row.

```
 select 
  -- If direction is I then generate an In tag
  case when direction = 'I' then id else null end as [In/@Id],
  case when direction = 'I' then direction else null end as [In],
  -- If direction is O then generate an Out tag
  case when direction = 'O' then id else null end as [Out/@Id],
  case when direction = 'O' then direction else null end as [Out]
 from devicepdo
 for xml path('')
```

Effectively you have expressions for all possible tags, but for rows where a type of tag is not desired, use a `case` statement to make the expression null.

Comment: You  made my day. Thank you very much for this solution! I would never have found out this myself!